# UIImage drawInRect:rect is too slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to write a simple program like:
If an user enters a number N (N < 100) then I draw N fish on the screen at random position on a UIView. I use the `drawInRect` but it's very slow. It takes about 10 ms to draw a 21 x 16 px image ON REAL DEVICE...so 100 fish will cost me about 1 second. I need a much faster approach (about 1ms per fish)

Is there any other way? I don't want to use Open GL b/s I need to do a lot of things with UIKIT....

this is My Draw Function:

```
void FishDraw(float px, float py)
{
    CGRect rect;


    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
    rect.size.width = fishimg.size.width;
    rect.size.height = fishimg.size.height;
    rect.origin.x = px;
    rect.origin.y = py;
    [fishimg drawInRect:rect];  
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
    timeInterval  *= 1000;
    NSLog(@"%f",timeInterval);
}
```

MY Fish is 21x16px , 32 Bit Color, at PNG Format costs 10 ms on to draw on real Device... Very Slow !

p/s : After one day, I found the good solution:
Used CGLayerRef and CGContextDrawLayerInRect is 10x - 15x faster than drawInRect.
Hope it's useful to you !

Comment: I assume you are providing your own code in drawInRect to draw the fish? If so, we need to see that. drawInRect is only as fast/slow as the code you put in there.

Comment: @sosborn `drawInRect:` is a method on `UIImage`, so it's part of the CocoaTouch framework.

Comment: If you don't have any code of your own code in drawInRect: then you shouldn't be calling it.

Comment: @sosborn: He's talking about drawInRect, not drawRect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you aren't REdrawing your fish every cycle.  drawInRect is not meant to be used (unless absolutely necessary) to redraw your visuals.  The idea is that drawInRect is called once and that output is cached for reuse.  So say if you have 100 fish, you call drawInRect once for each fish.  Further operations (movement, etc) are then just translations on the UIView.  E.g., view.frame.origin = CGMakePoint(100, 100), etc.  So when the app starts up, you draw 100 fish views and then move them off screen.  If the user enters 50, you move 50 fish views on screen.  If they enter 100, you move all 100 on screen.

Typically, each fish would be one UIView.  They are very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `NSLog`?

`NSLog` is very slow and the timer functionality also consumes time. If you need to measure the time don't do it for every fish, but for all of them.

**EDIT:** After learning what device you are using I would say that your device is too slow rather than your code.

I'm not sure what the purpose of your app is, but if you enter a number and the app will draw that number of fish, maybe the user finds it acceptable to wait for 1 second. So it might even be fast enough already.

Comment: Yep ! I tried it ! but it still slow . YOu can try my code on your devie, i think it would be the same speed

Comment: What device are you running on? I suppose the difference between an iPhone 4 and an iPhone 3G would be more than noticeable.

Comment: I used Ipod 2 ! but it cost 0.3ms to Fill A Rectangle of (0,0,100,100) but draw image is very slow @@

Comment: The second generation of iPod Touch is the equivalent of iPhone 3G performance wise, right? If so you're using a very slow device. I would say that performance may not even be a problem on newer devices. I mean there is a reason why Apple doesn't support multitasking for this model.

Comment: Thanks to all of you friends ^^!

I tried many option... but it still the same... so I will port them to OpenGL.

anyone would show me how to create a non-fullscreen OpenGL-View (like a OpenGL-UIView just in a rect of 0,0 , 320,200) ? so I can use UIKit to the rest of screen.

Thanks a lot!